# Using chart.update on a chart using renderTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I declare a highcart function locally:

```
function render(){
  var Chart=null
  Chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
          renderTo: container,
          height: 400
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Chart.update'
      },

      subtitle: {
          text: 'Plain'
      },

      xAxis: {
          categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
      },

      series: [{
          type: 'column',
          colorByPoint: true,
          data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
          showInLegend: false
      }]
  });
}
```

Assuming I cannot alter the render() function, am I able to use the chart.update tool to change the properties?

Basically I'd like to recreate the functionality [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-update/), but for [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/z9qmkt2p/2/) without altering the function.

Is this just like asking to access a local variable outside of the function or is it still defined somewhere globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define `var chart=null` at begging before the `render` function

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9qmkt2p/3/)

Js

```
var chart = null
function render() {
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: container,
      height: 400
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Chart.update'
    },

    subtitle: {
      text: 'Plain'
    },

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
      type: 'column',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
      showInLegend: false
    }]
  });
}
render()

function plain() {
  chart.update({
    chart: {
      inverted: false,
      polar: false
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Plain'
    }
  });
}

function inverted() {
  chart.update({
    chart: {
      inverted: true,
      polar: false
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Inverted'
    }
  });
}

function polar() {
  chart.update({
    chart: {
      inverted: false,
      polar: true
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Polar'
    }
  });
}
```

Html

```
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="plain" class="autocompare" onclick="plain()">Plain</button>
<button id="inverted" class="autocompare" onclick="inverted()">Inverted</button>
<button id="polar" class="autocompare" onclick="polar()">Polar</button>
```